# Watermark in existing PDF in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I would like to add a dynamically generated text. Is there a way to watermark an existing PDF in Ruby?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will do it:

`PDF::Reader` to count the number of pages in the file.

`Prawn` to create a new PDF document using each page of the input pdf as a template.

```
require 'prawn'
require 'pdf-reader'

input_filename = 'input.pdf'
output_filename = 'output.pdf'

page_count = PDF::Reader.new(input_filename).page_count

Prawn::Document.generate(output_filename, :skip_page_creation => true) do |pdf|

  page_count.times do |num|
    pdf.start_new_page(:template => input_filename, :template_page => num+1)
    pdf.text('WATERMARK')
  end

end
```

However, in my testing the output file size was huge with the latest Gem version of Prawn (0.12), but after pointing my Gemfile at the master branch on github, all worked fine.

Comment: You can pass the `:template` option to `Prawn::Document` and then just iterate through the pages that way. That will keep the output file size much closer to the input file size.

Comment: Prawn no longer supports editing/combining two PDFs into one. Check the answer by @Myst for an up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use PDFTK.  It can be used to add a watermark and create a new PDF.  Maybe prawn will do the same thing with it's templating.

`pdftk in.pdf background arecibo.pdf output wmark1.pdf`

Some more info: http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2009/pdf-watermark-margins/

There is a ruby wrapper gem called [active_pdftk](https://github.com/tcocca/active_pdftk) which supports backgrounding, so you don't have to do the shell commands yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Prawn doesn't support templates anymore...

Try the [combine_pdf gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf).

You can combine, watermark, page-number and add simple text to existing PDF files (including the creation of a simple table of contents without PDF links).

It's a very simple and basic PDF library, written in pure Ruby with no dependencies.

This example can fit your situation (it's from the readme file):

```
# load the logo as a pdf page
company_logo = CombinePDF.load("company_logo.pdf").pages[0]

# load the content file
pdf = CombinePDF.load "content_file.pdf"

# inject the logo to each page in the content
pdf.pages.each {|page| page << company_logo}

# save to a new file, with the logo.
pdf.save "content_with_logo.pdf"
```

Comment: Content file text not visibing, i've noticed the font color is geting white when  creating template using mac pages

Comment: @Subha , this might be an issue (or your PDF's background might be an opaque white rather than transparent), but this is definitely not the gem's normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Prawn(http://github.com/sandal/prawn) for just ruby and Prawnto(http://github.com/thorny-sun/prawnto) for Ruby on Rails.

You are probably going to want to either use the image embedding functionality or the background image functionality.

Here's an example of using a background image http://cracklabs.com/prawnto/code/prawn_demos/source/general/background

Comment: Prawn is only able to embed images to a fresh pdf created with prawn not an existing one ... so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: ah, missed the *existing* part in your post. Sorry about that. I don't believe there is, unless you were to convert it to an image and then watermark it.

Comment: Actually, it seems that Prawn can edit an existing PDF if you use that PDF as a template: http://groups.google.com/group/prawn-ruby/browse_thread/thread/a8dd9bb83d2c2abd?pli=1 & https://github.com/yob/prawn/tree/templates_2010 . I have not personally used these, but the information seems somewhat recent?

Answer (score -5):

Use [Ruport](https://github.com/ruport/ruport).

1st result for Googling `ruby pdf watermark`.

Comment: Duh... just shows the limits of Google. I'm looking for the same thing, and Ruport is not it.

Comment: Ruport uses PDF::Writer.  PDF::Writer only creates PDFs.  No go.